# Built-in way to parse any raw HTML

Tags: c#, .net, html, .net-2.0, html-parsing

I start writing an app that should retrieve meta tags content from any specified HTML page. As I use .NET 2.0 for this purpose I can't use LINQ to XML or something modern. So, I tried to use `XmlDocument` class. Unfortunately, it can't work with invalid XML documents, which are most HTML are.

I even can't use HtmlAgilityPack because I'm writing app that I plan to sell in future, so it probably doesn't fit commercial needs.

Working with `XmlReader` seems too hard.

So, how would you guys manage this issue?

---

***POST EDIT***

Another one reason why I better avoid using HtmlAgilityPack is that it is so huge lib to adding to my project. I will be more happy keeping project as small as possible.

Do you guys really advice me use HtmlAgilityPack any way?

Comment: What's wrong with HtmlAgilityPack?

Answer (score 5):

> I even can't use HtmlAgilityPack because I'm writing app that I plan
>   to sell in future, so it probably doesn't fit commercial needs.

[HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/license) is using a Microsoft Public License (Ms-PL), which will allow you to use it in a commercial product, it's very liberal - also see ["How does MS-PL license work?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1424307/how-does-ms-pl-license-work) and [Microsoft Public License (Ms-PL)](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/openness/resources/licenses.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
HtmlDocument doc = new System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser().Document.OpenNew(true);
doc.Write("<HTML><BODY>This is a new HTML document.</BODY></HTML>");
```

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmldocument.aspx).

Note that this is a WebForms control, you may face different issues running it out of WebForms app.